# What's a generic integer?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let us call a set $D\subseteq\mathbb Z$ *residue-class dense* if for each residue class $[a]_n=\{kn+a\mid k\in\mathbb Z\}$, there is a residue class $[b]_m$ with $[b]_m\subseteq [a]_n\cap D$.

Using the Sun-tzu (Chinese) Remainder Theorem we can see that examples of dense sets include the non-primes and the non-squares.
Moreover, if $D_1$ and $D_2$ are residue-class dense then so is $D_1\cap D_2$.

Elements of such dense sets can be thought of as generic integers. Thus, a generic integer is not prime, and not square.

I'm curious if this is a well-studied notion, under another name?

Comment: You don't say what $m$ is.  If you would replace whole residue classes $[b]_m$ in your definition by individual integers $b$ in $[a]_n \cap D$ then $D$ would be a dense subset of $\mathbf Z$ for the profinite topology.

Comment: @KConrad thanks for the comment. $m$ is such that $[b]_m\subseteq [a]_n$ which implies that $n$ divides $m$, I guess.

Comment: @KConrad perhaps my definition is equivalent to "comeager under the profinite topology".

Comment: Comeager = residual (which would then be a very evocative name here)